# android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException:

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have created my table using sqlite for my android project. It was working just fine before. Initially, I created 3 fields to make sure the connection will work and it did so I added all the other fields I will need but I was getting an error with the cursor. After reading similar problems here, i figured it will be an issue with the onUpgrade so i uninstalled the app and reinstalled but now it keeps crashing and I am getting a syntax error.

Here is my code

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){

        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE_SITE_INFO + " ("
                + ROW_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                + SYSAID_ID + " TEXT, "
                + SITE_ID + " TEXT, "
                + LINK_ID + " TEXT, "
                + CUSTOMER_NAME + " TEXT, "
                + SITE_CONTACT + " TEXT, "
                + TASK_TYPE + " TEXT, "
                + ADDRESS + " TEXT, "
                + REGION + " TEXT, "
                + PHONE + " TEXT, "
                + FAX + " TEXT, "
                + MOBILE + " TEXT, "
                + EMAIL + " TEXT, "
                + LANDLORD_NAME + " TEXT, "
                + RENT_STATUS + " TEXT, "
                + LOCATION + " TEXT, "
                + ENGINEER_NAME + " TEXT, "
                + ENGINEER_SIGN + " BLOB, "
                + POWER_STATUS + " TEXT, "
                + VOLTAGE_MEASUREMENT + " TEXT, "
                + AIRCON + " TEXT, "
                + SERVER_ROOM_STATUS + " TEXT, "
                + LOCATION_IDU + " TEXT, "
                + EARTHING + " TEXT, "
                + DISTANCE_IDU + " TEXT, "
                + SECURITY_CABLES + " TEXT, "
                + DUCTS + " TEXT, "
                + UNIT_TYPE + " TEXT, "
                + INST_TYPE + " TEXT, "
                + HAVE_ISP + " TEXT, "
                + RADIO + " TEXT, "
                + ISP_TYPE + " TEXT, "
                + ISP_NAME + " TEXT, "
                + SNR_RX + " TEXT, "
                + BS + " TEXT, "
                + REMARKS + " TEXT);");
```

And this is the error code i am getting

```
01-14 10:22:28.429  24406-24406/com.example.sweetiean.stlfieldinstallation1 E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.sweetiean.stlfieldinstallation1, PID: 24406
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.sweetiean.stlfieldinstallation1/com.example.sweetiean.stlfieldinstallation1.MainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "(": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE site_info_table(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, sysaid_id TEXT, site_id TEXT, link_id TEXT, customer_name TEXT, site_contact_name TEXT, task_type TEXT, address TEXT, region TEXT, phone TEXT, fax TEXT, mobile TEXT, email TEXT, landlord_name TEXT, rent_status TEXT, location TEXT, engineer_name TEXT, engineer_sign BLOB, power_status TEXT, voltage_measure TEXT, aircon TEXT, server_room_status TEXT, location_of_idu TEXT, earthing TEXT, distance_idu TEXT, security_of_cables TEXT, ducts TEXT, unit_to_be_installed TEXT, inst_type TEXT, isp TEXT, radio_type TEXT, isp_type TEXT, isp_name TEXT, snr(rx) TEXT, bs TEXT, remarks TEXT);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`snr(rx)` is not a valid column name because of the parentheses. Rename it to e.g. `snr_rx`.

Comment: Added "is not " before "a valid column name"

Comment: or if want to create column name as `snr(rx)` in table then use `[snr(rx)] TEXT` instead of `snr(rx) TEXT`

Comment: I dont have enough reputation points to upvote your answer but I need you to know that it worked. kudos!!

Comment: @DerGolem Thanks, writing while distracted by a coworker is not always a good idea.

Comment: ρяσѕρєяK, true, or `"snr(tx)"` or the same in backticks. But that would likely cause problems when using the column name in other constructs, so renaming it is better.